# Attempting to add additional functionality to javascript (

Tags: javascript, css, html, getelementbyid

FYI newb here
   I've managed to craft a small JavaScript that does 50% of what I want in that when i click it, it shows the links that are hidden. I'd like to add the additional functionality of when clicking the main link again, it will hide the links that have been revealed. So, what i think i'm trying to do is on first click, change the state of the hidden object to inline, on next click, change display back to 'none'.

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('displayLinks').style.display='inline';" ><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;Studies</a></li>
    <span id="displayLinks" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="current"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;216</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://southlore.net/collectiondetail.php?id=103" class="current"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;240</a></li>

            <li><a href="http://southlore.net/collectiondetail.php?id=103" class="current"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;240 Vids</a></li>
        </ul>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `toggle` function that switches between `inline` and `none`:

```
var toggle = (function() {
    var style = 'inline';
    return function() {
        document.getElementById('displayLinks').style.display=style;
        if (style == 'inline') {
            style = 'none';
        } else {
            style = 'inline';
        }
    }
})();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLLxk/)

Comment: A toggle? I never would of guess that idea in million years - thank you i will go and explore that - thanks for the fiddle.

Comment: @Chezshire, jquery already have a `.toggle` method, but since you didn't use it, I just used basic js

Comment: Thank you - i'm just tipping my toes into the waters of jQuery and javascript which is very amazing, but not always obvious as to how to do something. I was looking for something like 'changeEvent', the idea that it would be 'toggle' never entered my mind. Thanks for the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an if else

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="if(document.getElementById('displayLinks').style.display == 'none') { document.getElementById('displayLinks').style.display='inline'; } else {document.getElementById('displayLinks').style.display='none';}"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;Studies</a>

</li> <span id="displayLinks" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="current"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;216</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://southlore.net/collectiondetail.php?id=103" class="current"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;240</a></li>

            <li><a href="http://southlore.net/collectiondetail.php?id=103" class="current"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;240 Vids</a></li>
        </ul>
    </span>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gd7me/)